# Interchangeability of idiomatic "wavelength" and "frequency"

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions

Do these sentences mean the same?

> We don't have the same **wavelength**.
>
> We are not in the same **frequency**.

Comment: In physics the wavelength and frequency are inversely related (with a coefficient of proportionality of the wave propagation speed). In the context of radio (where v=c) they are equivalent, but not identical concepts.

Answer (score 4):

*[To be on the same wavelength](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-on-the-same-wavelength)* is a common idiom, but there is no such idiom for *frequency* though you could still use it metaphorically with the risk of not being understood.

Answer (score 3):

*"We don't have [the?] same wavelength"* sounds strange to me - the standard "set phrase" I'm familiar with is **"We're [not] on the same wavelength"**.

Other idiomatic phrases with similar meaning are ["We're singing from the same [hymn]sheet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workplace_jargon) and (less commonly) [We're on the same page](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic9451.html), but in my experience both these smack of "office jargon".

I don't think I've *ever* heard any variation of this metaphoric usage based on the word "frequency".